# How can I save a Custom TF model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To train a Capsule Network I created a custom tf model. Training works fine. However, when I try to save the model, the model.save() command is not working (Error: "Call arguments received: inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)']")
Full Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\janni\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4912/2003660347.py", line 1, in <module>
model.save(".\my_model")

File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\CapsNet\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\CapsNet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1129, in autograph_handler
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)

TypeError: in user code:

File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\CapsNet\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 125, in _wrapped_model  *
    outputs = model(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\CapsNet\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "capsule_network" (type CapsuleNetwork).

in user code:

    File "D:\Studium\Master_HSD\17_CapsNetProject\CapsuleNetworkClass.py", line 82, in call  *
        b = tf.zeros((input_x.shape[0], self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, 1)) # b.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)

    TypeError: Expected int32, but got None of type 'NoneType'.


Call arguments received:
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)']
```

So the source of the problem is the 'None' format of the input of the call function, which is used later to create the size of the variable b. I do not understand how to solve the issue since this dimension depends on the batch size. Any help on how to make my model class savable is much appreciated.

Specs:
TF 2.7
Python 3.8.12

Below is the Code of the Custom model class:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class CapsuleNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, input_dimension, no_channels, no_of_convs, kernel_sizes, conv_strides, no_of_conv_kernels, no_of_primary_capsules, primary_capsule_vector, no_of_secondary_capsules, secondary_capsule_vector, r):
    super(CapsuleNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.input_dimension = input_dimension
    self.no_channels = no_channels
    self.no_of_convs = no_of_convs
    self.kernel_sizes = kernel_sizes
    self.conv_strides = conv_strides
    self.no_of_conv_kernels = no_of_conv_kernels
    self.no_of_primary_capsules = no_of_primary_capsules
    self.primary_capsule_vector = primary_capsule_vector
    self.no_of_secondary_capsules = no_of_secondary_capsules
    self.secondary_capsule_vector = secondary_capsule_vector
    self.r = r
    self.epsilon = 10e-7
    
    # calculating the number of primary capsules based on input image size and kernels/strides of the convolution (1152 in the paper)
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        if i == 0:
            self.feature_map_dim = int(((input_dimension-self.kernel_sizes[i])/self.conv_strides[i])+1)
        else:
            self.feature_map_dim = int(((self.feature_map_dim-self.kernel_sizes[i])/self.conv_strides[i])+1)
            
    self.feature_map_dim = int(((self.feature_map_dim-self.kernel_sizes[-1])/self.conv_strides[-1])+1)
    self.no_primary_caps = int(self.feature_map_dim*self.feature_map_dim*self.no_of_primary_capsules)
    
    with tf.name_scope("Variables") as scope:
        self.conv_dict = {}
        for i in range(no_of_convs):
            self.conv_dict[f"convolution{i}"] = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.no_of_conv_kernels, [self.kernel_sizes[i],self.kernel_sizes[i]], strides=[self.conv_strides[i],self.conv_strides[i]], name=f'ConvolutionLayer_{i}', activation='relu')
        self.primary_capsule = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.no_of_primary_capsules * self.primary_capsule_vector, [self.kernel_sizes[-1],self.kernel_sizes[-1]], strides=[self.conv_strides[-1],self.conv_strides[-1]], name="PrimaryCapsule")
        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal_initializer()(shape=[1, self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, self.secondary_capsule_vector, self.primary_capsule_vector]), dtype=tf.float32, name="PoseEstimation", trainable=True)
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 512, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1024, activation='relu')
        self.dense_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = input_dimension*input_dimension*no_channels, activation='sigmoid', dtype='float32')

def print_architecture(self):
    print("Model Summary:\n")
    print("Input images: " + str(self.input_dimension) + "x" + str(self.input_dimension) + "x" + str(self.no_channels))
    print(str(self.no_of_convs) + " conv layers")
    print(str(self.no_of_primary_capsules) + " primary capsule channels with " + str(self.no_primary_caps) + " " + str(self.primary_capsule_vector) + "-D capsules")
    print(str(self.no_of_secondary_capsules) + " " + str(self.secondary_capsule_vector) + "-D digit capsules")
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    pass
    
def squash(self, s):
    with tf.name_scope("SquashFunction") as scope:
        s_norm = tf.norm(s, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return tf.square(s_norm)/(1 + tf.square(s_norm)) * s/(s_norm + self.epsilon)

@tf.function
def call(self, inputs):
    input_x, y = inputs
    
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        convolution = self.conv_dict.get(f"convolution{i}")
        if i == 0:
            x = convolution(input_x) # x.shape: (None, 20, 20, 256) JB:stimmt nun nicht mehr zwangsläufig
        else:
            x = convolution(x)
    x = self.primary_capsule(x) # x.shape: (None, 6, 6, 256)
    
    with tf.name_scope("CapsuleFormation") as scope:
        u = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.no_of_primary_capsules * x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], self.primary_capsule_vector)) # u.shape: (None, 2048, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-2) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-1) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8, 1)
        u_hat = tf.matmul(self.w, u) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
        u_hat = tf.squeeze(u_hat, [4]) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16)

    
    with tf.name_scope("DynamicRouting") as scope:
        b = tf.zeros((input_x.shape[0], self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, 1)) # b.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
        for i in range(self.r): # self.r = 3
            c = tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=-2) # c.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            s = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(c, u_hat), axis=1, keepdims=True) # s.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            v = self.squash(s) # v.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            agreement = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(u_hat, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(v, axis=-1), transpose_a=True), [4]) # agreement.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            # Before matmul following intermediate shapes are present, they are not assigned to a variable but just for understanding the code.
            # u_hat.shape (Intermediate shape) : (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
            # v.shape (Intermediate shape): (None, 1, 10, 16, 1)
            # Since the first parameter of matmul is to be transposed its shape becomes:(None, 1152, 10, 1, 16)
            # Now matmul is performed in the last two dimensions, and others are broadcasted
            # Before squeezing we have an intermediate shape of (None, 1152, 10, 1, 1)
            b += agreement
            
    with tf.name_scope("Masking") as scope:
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=-1) # y.shape: (None, 10, 1)
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1) # y.shape: (None, 1, 10, 1)
        mask = tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.float32) # mask.shape: (None, 1, 10, 1)
        v_masked = tf.multiply(mask, v) # v_masked.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
        
    with tf.name_scope("Reconstruction") as scope:
        v_ = tf.reshape(v_masked, [-1, self.no_of_secondary_capsules * self.secondary_capsule_vector]) # v_.shape: (None, 160)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_1(v_) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 512)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_2(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 1024)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_3(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 784)
    return v, reconstructed_image

@tf.function
def predict_capsule_output(self, inputs):
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        convolution = self.conv_dict.get(f"convolution{i}")
        if i == 0:
            x = convolution(inputs) # x.shape: (None, 20, 20, 256) JB:stimmt nun nicht mehr zwangsläufig
        else:
            x = convolution(x)
    x = self.primary_capsule(x) # x.shape: (None, 6, 6, 256)
    
    with tf.name_scope("CapsuleFormation") as scope:
        u = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.no_of_primary_capsules * x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], self.primary_capsule_vector)) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-2) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-1) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8, 1)
        u_hat = tf.matmul(self.w, u) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
        u_hat = tf.squeeze(u_hat, [4]) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16)

    
    with tf.name_scope("DynamicRouting") as scope:
        b = tf.zeros((inputs.shape[0], self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, 1)) # b.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
        for i in range(self.r): # self.r = 3
            c = tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=-2) # c.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            s = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(c, u_hat), axis=1, keepdims=True) # s.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            v = self.squash(s) # v.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            agreement = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(u_hat, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(v, axis=-1), transpose_a=True), [4]) # agreement.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            # Before matmul following intermediate shapes are present, they are not assigned to a variable but just for understanding the code.
            b += agreement
    return v

@tf.function
def regenerate_image(self, inputs):
    
    with tf.name_scope("Reconstruction") as scope:
        v_ = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, self.no_of_secondary_capsules * self.secondary_capsule_vector]) # v_.shape: (None, 160)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_1(v_) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 512)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_2(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 1024)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_3(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 3072)
    return reconstructed_image
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the full stack trace (the error message)? It would help.

Comment: you need to implement a class-member function that takes `self` and save tf.keras.Model. Even though the implementation of the capsule network seems incomplete.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by incomplete?